# Shopping cart views are not show product links

Tags: commerce

I am using Commerce Kickstart V t-7.x-2.2

I realized the next: When I add a new product and I add to cart it, not show the link "view product" . But when I edit that product and modify something on product variation and save again. The link "view product" appears in Shopping cart.

Somebody could tell me what is happening? Is it a bug of the commerce kickstart ? or Am I doing something wrong?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the shopping cart views, go to 
admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form/edit/default

On the Fields Setting Make sure there is Display path field, exclude from display. see the Global: Custom text, and you must inlcude the Dsiplay path field token there